# Running JSONata in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, jsonata

I'm doing a project in javascript for the frontend and java for the backend. I'm using JSONata to parse incoming json (it's great) on the frontend. It works great on all the browsers EXCEPT Internet Explorer.

The code is basically (where I'm using JSONata):

```
$.ajax({ 

            dataType: 'json',
            cache : false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "consult", 
            data: {"id": id},
            success: function(data) {   
                console.log("data", data);
                var claim = jsonata('$[0].data.claim').evaluate(data);
}
```

This works no problem in all the browsers EXCEPT Internet Explorer where I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'jsonata' is undefined
```

Is JSONata not suitable for internet explorer? or is there a way I can bypass this?

Also, I thought well if I can't run it on client side, I'll run JSONata on the server, so I tried this code:

```
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    FileReader jsonata = new FileReader("jsonata.js");

    engine.eval(jsonata);

    // read and JSON.parse the input data
    byte[] sample = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("sample.json"));
    engine.put("input", new String(sample));
    Object inputjson = engine.eval("JSON.parse(input);");

    // query the data
    String expression = "$sum(Account.Order.Product.(Price * Quantity))";  // JSONata expression
    Object expr = inv.invokeFunction("jsonata", expression);
    Object resultjson = inv.invokeMethod(expr, "evaluate", inputjson);

    // JSON.stringify the result
    engine.put("resultjson", resultjson);
    Object result = engine.eval("JSON.stringify(resultjson);");
    System.out.println(result);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1448:25 Expected an operand but found yield
            result = yield evaluatePath(expr.steps, input, environment);
                     ^ in <eval> at line number 1448 at column number 25
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:537)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:150)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
at com.test.main.Main.main(Main.java:67)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1448:25 Expected an operand but found yield
            result = yield evaluatePath(expr.steps, input, environment);
                     ^
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:294)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:279)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3182)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3325)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3282)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expressionStatement(Parser.java:1150)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:967)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:863)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statementList(Parser.java:1013)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.getBlock(Parser.java:531)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.switchStatement(Parser.java:1717)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:917)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionBody(Parser.java:2901)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionExpression(Parser.java:2663)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:875)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionBody(Parser.java:2901)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionExpression(Parser.java:2663)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.memberExpression(Parser.java:2506)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2372)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3282)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.primaryExpression(Parser.java:1992)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.memberExpression(Parser.java:2511)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2372)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.assignmentExpression(Parser.java:3353)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.variableStatement(Parser.java:1088)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:884)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.program(Parser.java:709)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:283)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:249)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1284)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535)
... 5 more
```

PD: I'm using jsonata.js (from their website: https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/blob/master/jsonata.js"

How can I run JSONata so that is it compatible across all browsers (specially in Internet Explorer)

Thank you very much!

Comment: The fact that `jsonata` is undefined means there was a problem loading the jsonata library from github (or it took too long). If you open the dev console (F12) and reload the page (F5), are there any errors in the console, or some http errors on the Network tab?

Comment: This is the error that comes up in the console: 
    SCRIPT5009: 'jsonata' is undefined. 
Also, I'm inputting the jsonata.js directly as a file, I'm not having it read from github.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were saying you loaded the library from the github site... Anyway, can you show *how* you are loading the local copy of the `jsonata.js` file?

Comment: I put this line in a ".jsp" file: <script src="js/jsonata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. The project works perfectly fine in every browser except Internet Explorer. I have no idea why it doesn't work in Internet Explorer, is it not compatible?

Comment: It depends upon *where* in the page that script is placed. It sounds like a timing issue -- IE is trying to use the `jsonata` library before it is fully loaded. Did you verify in the browser's dev console that the relative path "js/jsonata.js" is actually loading the library through that url correctly (no 404 or 500 errors)? I've seen IE do some weird things with relative urls and proxies...

Comment: I placed it at the very top and nothing :(. What I've also been doing is pulling the jsonata.js apart, just putting in some code and seeing if it works, and I've gotten to the point that it fails with the message: "SCRIPT5009: 'jsonata' is undefined" when I include a line that has the "yield" function: like so:    switch (expr.type) {
            case 'path':
                result = yield * evaluatePath(expr.steps, input, environment);
                result = normalizeSequence(result, expr.keepSingletonArray);
                break;

That code is directly from jsonata.js by the way.

Comment: Also if you go to their website on internet explorer to try jsonata: "http://try.jsonata.org/", it also wont work on their own page :(

Comment: Well that certainly is *not* working as designed then... notified the author (Andrew Coleman) on his slack channel, so it should get resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much SteveR for the help. Did you mean that you already notified him? or that I should notify him?

Comment: Yes, I did send him a link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with ES6 dependencies. Try using `jsonata-es5.js`.  You can build this using `npm t` or pull it directly from [here](https://unpkg.com/jsonata@1.5.2/jsonata-es5.js).

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it almost works. In one part of the code i'm extracting properties normally with jsonata: `info = jsonata('[xml.resume.{"date" : date, "field2": field2}]').evaluate(data);` and then I want to add a counter, because its several objects, so I have this code: `info = jsonata('$ ~> $map(function($v, $i) {$merge([{\'count\': $i+1}, $v])})').evaluate(info);`. But that changes info into an Object Generator (according to Internet Explorer): [object Generator]. before I merge it with the count, it does output a correct object though, do I have to change the merge function?

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you see what I commented above? The merge function is not functioning correctly, it's giving me an Object Generator instead of an object with the "count" variable added.